# Are $\mathbb{C}[x]/x^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}[x]/x^2$ and $\mathbb{C}[x]/x^2$ isomorphic as $\mathbb{C}[x]/x^2$-modules?

Tags: modules, tensor-products

Are $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{x^2} \otimes \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{x^2}$ and $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{x^2}$ isomorphic as  $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{x^2}$-modules? I believe that they are but it I know that there is a mistake in my working and this is the claim that I'm the most uncertain of.

Comment: Is the tensor product over $\Bbb{C}$ or over $\Bbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$ or something else?

Comment: The second; the tensor product is over $\mathbb{C}[x]/x^2$

Comment: $R\otimes_R M \cong M$ for any $R$-module $M$.  In particular, $R\otimes_R R \cong R$.

Comment: Okay thanks! I guess I'll have to find some other issue with my work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any ring $R$ and any $R$-module $M$ we have $M\otimes_RR\cong M$ canonically. Taking $R=M=\Bbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$ yields the desired result.